# Exporting chart from Windows performance analyzer

Tags: windows-performance-analyzer

I would like to export the time series  of a single process, as the one highlighted in blue.

[image]

I tried to export the tables following the procedure proposed by Bruce Dawson.

Is-it possible to export the time-series directly from WPA?
Shall I use C# and the nuget package as suggested by Bruce Dawson?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using WPAExporter?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/exporter

To get started, you'll need to create a filter on the table data and export a profile. This process is done through the View Editor for the particular table in WPA, which offers an advanced dialog box. Inside this dialog, you'll find a 'Filter' tab where you can define your specific conditions using WPA query syntax. For more details on the syntax, refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/wpa-query-syntax. Additionally, you can find a guide on using the View Editor here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/view-editor.

Then, you can export the filtered profile via the "Profiles -> Export..." context menu. A good rule of thumb is to apply the filter with WPA first, as this will give you a clear picture of what WPA Exporter will extract from the trace.

Thanks,

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

WPAExporter is a solid tool and the first answer has some good links. I blogged about my experience with it here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/exporting-arbitrary-data-from-xperf-etl-files/

In theory using WPAExporter is simpler than writing .Net code to export data, but in practice it can be just as finicky, and I have no love of .csv files. So, my normal export methods these days are either copy/paste (simple, gives you tab-separated data) or Trace Processor (https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/01/05/bulk-etw-trace-analysis-in-c/). Trace Processor is more work but if I'm going to be analyzing multiple traces or I want to generate some stats in addition to exporting then it is clearly superior.